# Where can I download RiaServices.msi nowadays?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Where can I download RiaServices.msi from the web, after Microsoft removed it?

I need to prepare a new virtual machine to host a legacy Silverlight application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, downloading ria.services separately may not be easy to find at the moment, you can use [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RIAServices.Silverlight#readme-body-tab) to install it.

Comment: Hi! I assume that by "install" you mean: 1: Run NuGet on the target machine to get the package. 2: rename the .pkg file to .zip, and extract its contents. 3: run some .script file there that will put the file in the right places on the targe machine. Correct?

Comment: Yes. You can try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

After the hint from @Jiayao, I decided to forget about the RiaServices.msi installer and manually copy the necessary files to the target host machine, where the Silverlight app was published.

Luckily the files simply need to be copied to the silverlight "bin" folder.

The files I copied were:

- System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.dll
- System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Web.dll
- System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll
- System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll

These libraries are available in the "lib" folder of [riaservices.silverlight.4.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RIAServices.Silverlight/4.2.0) and [riaservices.server.4.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RIAServices.Server)  NuGet packages. You can download the packages, rename the .nupkg files to .zip and extract them.

If I have the chance to compile the Silverlight application from the source, I plan to add these NuGet packages as dependencies of the project, so they can be normally deployed within the Silverlight application.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to install the RIA WCF Services is to use Visual Studio 2015 installation in custom mode and to tick "Silverlight Development Kit". It works, I just did it a few minutes ago.
A bit overkill, perhaps...
... and well, you'll have to find an installer for VS 2015, too.